# Episerver 5 child pages urls export MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, episerver

I am trying to export specific pages child pages into some kind of list. The purpose of this is because I am updating a web site which is on episerver 5 to the new which is on episerver 7. The links should be updated as well, meaning I want to redirect all the current child pages to go to the new parent link. And I don't want to use a catch all since I want to show the 404 page if the child page doesn't exist.

Example:
Parent page, current web:
http://localhost/newssection/

Parent page, new web:
http://localhost/news/

All child pages from the current web should redirect 301 to the parent page for the new web.
Example of child pages:
http://localhost/newssection/what-is-going-on/ should redirect 301 to http://localhost/news/ and so on...

I want to build a script that generates all these redirects with rewrites for all the parent pages I select. How can I achieve this the best way?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously nearly endless ways of achieving this, but two viable options are:

1) Use rewrite rules in IIS (if you can use a common pattern or have a limited number of redirects)

2) Create a custom redirect, potentially as an HTTP module or an action filter on your page controller base class, and redirect to a URL set on each page

For option 2) you would probably add a new property called something like "LegacyUrl" on your base page type. It would be used to specify which old URL the new page is replacing.

For each page request resulting in a 404, look up the URL among the legacy URLs and redirect with "permanently moved" status code.

Comment: Thanks Ted, but this doesn't really answer my question. In essence, what I'm trying to achieve is to get a list of a pages children URLs. Then redirect all of these to the parent. However using a custom redirect will not work in my case since I don't know which URLs are to respond with 404 and which are to redirect to the parent by just looking at the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple page and do something like:

```
var children = DataFactory.Instance.GetChildren(new PageReference(IdToParentPage));
foreach (var child in children) {
Response.WriteLine(child.URLSegment); // this is only the segment for the page, not the full URL
}
```

And from that create rewrite-rules in web.config or add to it to some 404 module if you have that.

If you need the full URL you can get it with the following code:

```
EPiServer.UrlBuilder url = new EPiServer.UrlBuilder(child.LinkURL);
EPiServer.Global.UrlRewriteProvider.ConvertToExternal(url, child.PageLink, System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
```